# How to fix "Prop spreading is forbidden" in specialized component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to specialize TextField component to handle multiline feedback from customers. It looks like the following:

```
function AdditionalTextField(props) {
  return <TextField {...props} InputProps={{ style: { background: 'white' } }} fullWidth required={false} multiline rows={3} />;
}
```

Unfortunately eslint complains that I should avoid spreading props:

```
118:21   error    Prop spreading is forbidden  react/jsx-props-no-spreading
```

Should I pass every possible prop to the underlying TextField one by one? Is there any better solution in this case?

Comment: I mean that's an [ESLint rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md), you could ignore it for this line or this file.

Or customize it to allow it globally in your project.

Comment: First of all - how an I ignore it for this single one? And a second question - should I? Is there a better approach to achieve the same thing?

Comment: It's a rule to enforce a code convention with pros and cons. It's up to whoever manages the code base to decide whether bypassing it one time is acceptable or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you if you *should* ignore it, but you *can* ignore the warning like this:

```
function AdditionalTextField(props) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-props-no-spreading
  return <TextField {...props} InputProps={{ style: { background: 'white' } }} fullWidth required={false} multiline rows={3} />;
}
```

Comment: Ok. Is there a better way to "specialize" such a TextField component? If not then I will use this comment.

Comment: Not really. You can either spread the props or apply specific ones. An alternative might be to pick or omit certain props to create a black- or whitelist, and then spread those. As far as the lint rule is concerned, there are options that you can specify to suit your needs, for example ignoring the rule only for custom components or for html: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md